# alerts when a message box appears visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vba

Does any one of you guys have an idea on how to make an alert message or make a notification when a pop-up message appears?

example :

1. I created a message box named "ERROR"
2. Now I have to make something (either a message box again) that will alert me that this "ERROR" message box appears.

it's like error handling but you are catching a message box not an actual error.

P.S: ONCE THE MESSAGE BOX APPEAR EVEN WITHOUT CLICKING ANY BUTTONS IT SHOULD NOTIFY/ALERT

Hope someone can help me with my problem. I'm a newbie when it comes to visual studio 
or if there are other ways to make something like this on other languages. Please let me know. THANK YOU !

Comment: Why the Java tag? I'm not sure how this question relates to Java programming -- please clarify.

Comment: Is it a custom error message userform or somthing inbuilt like `MsgBox`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I removed the java tag. But just in case java can solve my problem that will be helpful.

Comment: yes its a custom message box pankaj.

Comment: You'll want to stick to one language when asking questions here.

Comment: I see, then I'll be sticking with visual studio then. If you have any idea for this problem let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (using VBA)

1- Create a `UserForm1` - custom error message

[image]

2- Have the following code in the userform

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Raise Error
    On Error Resume Next
    Call Err.Raise(666, "Test", "Test")
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'Ignore Error
    On Error Resume Next
    Call Err.Raise(667, "Test", "Test")
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

3- In `Module1`

```
Sub Test()
    If Err.Number = 666 Then
        MsgBox "error happened"
    End If
End Sub
```

4- In 'ThisWorkbook'

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show
    Call Test
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i create a thisworkbook ? sorry, im a newbie.

Comment: Its just a sample code. You may have to modify to suit your need. In Excel Automation, when you do `Alt+F11`, you will see all the code sheets, including `ThisWorkbook`. You don't have to create it. It allows you to automate based on the current workbook events like `Workbook Open` or `Workbook Before Close`.

Comment: Basically, I just tried to show how to raise custom error messages and how to use it in your code. Since you are working in VB.NET (assuming), you may have to put it in your main function or somewhere where you want to catch the error.